# ModuleNotFoundError for folder when using PyInstaller on Windows command line

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, kivy, python-import, pyinstaller

I am building a kivy app on PyCharm. My Test.py imports testone.py and runs a function from it. When I run Test.py in PyCharm the app builds and runs fine.  But then, to build the .exe for the app, I run the following in the command line:

```
python -m PyInstaller --name TestAppWD9 --onefile --add-data "Desktop\KivyUdemyCourse\AdvKivywKV\testone.py;Desktop\KivyUdemyCourse\AdvKivywKV\testone.py" C:\Users\jgldm\Desktop\KivyUdemyCourse\AdvKivywKV\Test.py
```

I get something like this as a spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew
import pygame.pkgdata

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\jgldm\\Desktop\\KivyUdemyCourse\\AdvKivywKV\\Test.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\jgldm'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('Desktop\\KivyUdemyCourse\\AdvKivywKV\\testone.py', 'Desktop\\KivyUdemyCourse\\AdvKivywKV\\testone.py')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
          [],
          name='TestAppWD9',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

when I run the app built from the spec file I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AdvKivywKV'

How can I get the spec file to find and include AdvKivywKV?

Comment: Do you have `AdvKivywKV` in the same folder when you're running it on Windows?

Comment: Build the app for windows? Is this a feature I'm not aware of?

Comment: @user124 https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html

Comment: @HSK AdvKivywKV is the common folder of both Test.py and testone.py. I want to import a function from testone.py into Test.py.

Comment: @HSK: I didn't move the common folder between builds

Comment: @eyllanesc I wasn't sure about the formulation of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder structure needed to be fixed by placing testone.py into a subfolder with an `__init__.py` file. The latter can be blank. After this I changed the import to `from subfolder_name.testone import function`